# "Gastronomy winds"?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

I'm trying to find a way to translate a title with a direct translation "Gastronomy winds blowing from X". I don't think it sounds pretty in English, plus can't find a better alternative other than changing the whole title. The original title refers to a culinary festival held in a town known for its strong winds.

What would you recommend in keeping with this context?

Thanks in advance, looking forward to your personal choice.

Comment: There's a problem with using [wind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wind#wind__11) at all. I've often wondered what the principal diet is in Chicago.

Comment: I would not go with a direct translation. As @AndrewLeach daintily pointed out, any association with food would lead some readers' minds to flatus. Could you alter the title a little, perhaps referencing a predominant spice, such as "The Saffron winds" or "The Scent of Cardamom"?

Comment: This is a very old association, from a very old euphemism of _wind_ for _fart_. It even has a mild patriotic aspect for certain Americans, because of [Benjamin Franklin's famous essay](http://www.philly.com/philly/blogs/public_health/Ben-Franklins-Treatise-on-Wind.html).

Comment: Oh the actual case the title refers to is a festival. So I cannot refer to particular flavor.

Comment: Epicurean aromas/flavours wafting across (name of city)?

Comment: I think I'd better change the whole title. But thank you anyways, guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if one is seeking to describe the scent of a food being wafted by the breeze, one would look to the word [aroma](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aroma).  To wit:

> a :  a distinctive pervasive and usually pleasant or savory smell; broadly :  odor

Thus "Aromatic breezes from X" would probably be your best translation.

Comment: This looks by far the best! Can I say instead The Gastronomic Waves Rising from X ?

Answer (score 5):

A direct translation won't have the connotation you want.  In general, "food winds" (or similar) creates a connotation of flatus, either out the front or the back.

You can use spices to describe the winds, which will not have a connotation of flatus (or, at least not as much).  For example, like rajah9 suggested:  "the saffron winds" or "the rosemary winds".

However, I would try to stay away from the word "wind" if possible.  "Scent" is a much better word, and does not carry such euphemistic baggage.  I know you want to keep the "wind" aspect, so I would keep "blowing", which conveys the windiness.

Something like (again, to borrow brow rajah9):  "Scents of Cardamom blowing from X".

---

Since the scent idea is out, what about directly referring to the culinary festival:

> Food festival blows into X

Comment: Oh Nick, as I replied the other comments, I don't mean a particular taste or thing here. The title wholly refers to a festival, culinary festival.

Comment: @Reactor4 What about "Food festival blows into X"?

Comment: I think I'd better change the whole title to "cooking spree" or something. Otherwise, it won't be compromised with its authentic connotation. But thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not only is *wind* an unfortunately compromised word when used in relation to food, but *gastronomy* is somewhat less lovely in English (where it shares a root with *gastrointestinal*, and where in any case the first syllable is *gas*) than its cognate perhaps is in French.

You could convey the original wording's intended fanfare regarding the significance of X as a gastronomic event to by rendering the title as "Culinary Currents Flowing From X"—with no unpleasant suggestion of an ill wind. And depending on how high-brow the festival is, you might replace "Culinary" in the title with "Gourmet" or "Epicurean."

Comment: Yeah I didn't paraphrase the trasnalation in any way. So of course I wouldn't go with the wind thing. "Gourmet currents flowing from x" could be a good choice indeed. If it sounds well. It still sounds a bit unnatural to my ears. So I'd better change the whole title into something else. :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid *wind* at all cost. It's synonymous with *gas*, as others have pointed out.

If you want to stick to a meteorological theme, how about **Gastronomy Climes of X**, though this might be a little esoteric. Other options:

**Gastronomy Currents of X**

**Gastronomical Landscape of X**